# $.post not working upon sucess

Tags: forms, onsubmit

I am creating a form using ideal forms and i am facing a problem upon submit.
If there is an invalid field then i get the correct message but when all data is ok then nothing happens when the correct action is to send the data to another page called new_ama.php 
Can you help out please????

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="el" class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="el" class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="el" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->   
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="el" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html lang="el">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/2.1.3/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.idealforms.css">
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Μητρώο Ασφαλισμένου</title> 
<style>
body {
max-width: 1980px;
margin: 2em auto;
font: normal 15px/1.5 Arial, sans-serif;
color: #353535;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
.content {
margin: 0 30px; 
}
.field.buttons button {
margin-right: .5em;
}
#invalid {
display: none;
float: left;
width: 290px;
margin-left: 120px;
margin-top: .5em;
color: #CC2A18;
font-size: 130%;
font-weight: bold;
}
.idealforms.adaptive #invalid {
margin-left: 0 !important;
}
.idealforms.adaptive .field.buttons label {
height: 0;
}
</style>
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"> </script></div>
<div class="jquery-script-clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
<h1 style="margin-top:150px;" align="center">Φόρμα Εγγραφής Ασφαλισμένου</h1>
<div class="content">
<div class="idealsteps-container">
<nav class="idealsteps-nav"></nav>
<form action="/" method="post" novalidate autocomplete="off" class="idealforms">
<div class="idealsteps-wrap"> 
<section class="idealsteps-step">
<div align="center">
<label align="center">Μέθοδος Αποστολής Δικαιολογητικών & Επικοινωνίας</label>
</div>
<fieldset>
<legend>Μέθοδος Αποστολής Δικαιολογητικών</legend>
<div class="field">
<p class="group">
<input name="docs" type="radio"  id="docs_uploaded" value="upload_docs">
<label>Ανέβασμα Αρχείων</label>
<input name="docs" type="radio" id="docs_posted" value="post_docs">
<label>Αποστολή με ταχυδρομείο</label>
</p>
<span class="error"></span> </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend>Επιλέξτε πως θέλετε να λαμβάνετε πληροφόρηση από το ΤΕΑΥΦΕ</legend>
<div class="field">
<p class="group">
<input name="contact[]" type="checkbox" value="ΤΑΧΥΔΡΟΜΕΙΟ">
<label>Με ταχυδρομείο</label>
<input name="contact[]" type="checkbox" value="ΤΗΛΕΦΩΝΟ">
<label>Με τηλέφωνο</label>
<input name="contact[]" type="checkbox" value="EMAIL">
<label>Με e-mail</label>
</p>
<span class="error"></span> </div>
</fieldset>
<div class="field buttons">
<label class="main">&nbsp;</label>
<button type="button" class="prev">&laquo; Προηγούμενο</button>
<button type="submit" class="submit">Υποβολή</button>
</div>
</section>
</div>
<span id="invalid"></span>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/out/jquery.idealforms.js"></script> 
<!--<script src="js/out/jquery.idealforms.min.js"></script>--> 
<script>

$('form.idealforms').idealforms({

  silentLoad: false,

  rules: {
    'contact[]': 'minoption:1 maxoption:3',
    'docs': 'minoption:1',
    'id_card': 'extension:jpg:pdf',
    'work_contract': 'extension:jpg:pdf'
  },

onSubmit: function(invalid, e) {
e.preventDefault();

if (invalid) {
  alert(invalid +' fields!');
} else {
$.post('new_ama.php');
}
}
});

$('form.idealforms').find('input, select, textarea').on('change keyup', function() {
  $('#invalid').hide();
});

$('.prev').click(function(){
  $('.prev').show();
  $('form.idealforms').idealforms('prevStep');
});
$('.next').click(function(){
  $('.next').show();
  $('form.idealforms').idealforms('nextStep');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On form action put  new_ama.php so
action=" new_ama.php"

Comment: i have tried it already but it doesn't work. The problem is within the onsubmit function.